Prevent GridLayout column width from stretching as if there were other columns
I have a programmatically created GridLayout that renders time slots within a specific day (such as an appointment time). At a maximum, each row should have 4 evenly spaced even width items, and at a minimum 1 item with a width matching the items in other rows.
The problem is that single items in a row seem to stretch to fill the available space. I would like to find a way to prevent items from stretching.
This is what the UI currently look like (click for larger version):

This is what I would like it to look like:

As you can see in the second photo, the single column is the same width as items in rows with multiple columns.
I've removed irrelevant code for brevity. Here's the code for the individual item Views:

class AppointmentSlotView(...): AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {


    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        setPadding(0, 18, 0, 18)
    }

    init {

        // ...
      
        isClickable = true
        gravity = Gravity.CENTER

        setOnClickListener { ... }

        background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_background_periwinkle_selector)
        maxLines = 1
        isSingleLine = true

    }
}

Here's the code that creates the GridLayout and adds the individual items:
filteredSlots.forEach {                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                              
    val gridLayout = GridLayout(this)                                                         
    gridLayout.columnCount = 4                                                                
                                                                                              
    it.value.forEachIndexed { index, slot ->                                                  
        // Create view                                                                        
        val view = AppointmentSlotView(this)                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                              
        val layoutParams: GridLayout.LayoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams(                  
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),                                        
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)).apply {                                
            width = 0                                                                         
            height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT                                                
        }                                                                                     
                                                                                              
        layoutParams.topMargin = 16.pxToDp(this)                                              
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = 16.pxToDp(this)                                           
        // First column                                                                       
        if (index % 4 == 0) {                                                                 
           layoutParams.marginEnd = 36.pxToDp(this)                                           
        } else if ((index + 1) % 4 == 0) {                                                    
            // Fourth column.                                                                 
        } else {                                                                              
            layoutParams.marginEnd = 36.pxToDp(this)                                          
        }                                                                                     
        gridLayout.addView(view, layoutParams)                                                
    }                                                                                         
    gridLayout.invalidate()                                                                   
    wrapper.addView(gridLayout)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                             

How can I achieve the UI in the second picture?
Thank you!

Have you tried using weight in GridLayout.LayoutParams or using min-width for AppointmentSlotView ?

Yes, I have. Unless I'm mistaken, the GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f) line sets the column weight. It works great for rows with 4 items and distributes the space evenly, but then stretch items that are the only item in their column, which is what I want to avoid.

Maybe RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager is the solution? In GridLayoutManager we can set a fixed SpanCount like GridLayoutManager(context, 4); for 4 columns.

I have a solution. But before I post , did you solve it alrady?

No, it has not been solved.

The properties you're looking for are GridLayout.LayoutParams.
For example:
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_columnWeight="1.00"


android:layout_columnWeight The relative proportion of horizontal space that should be allocated to this view during excess space distribution.

When generating it from scratch, this can still be styled:
private static final int COLUMN_WEIGHT = R.styleable.GridLayout_Layout_layout_columnWeight;

When 1.00 doesn't yield the desired result, try 0.25 (assuming 4 columns).

I believe I have already set the column weight (GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)). It works fine for distributing space between 4 elements, but then causes elements that are the only one in their row to stretch, which it what I'd like to avoid. Please let me know if I've misunderstood your answer!

The size "width" of the AppCompatTextView item need to be specified using the three-argument Column Spec method
To have only 1 column width for the item specify the 2nd parameter:
// The second param "1" is how many columns the item should span
layoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f) 
....
gridLayout.addView(view, layoutParams) 


Not much different from the question, which uses the constructor: LayoutParams(GridLayout.Spec rowSpec, GridLayout.Spec columnSpec)

I've attempted to use the three parameter constructor, passing 1 as the size parameter, but it does not seem to have an effect on the issue. I imagine the default size is already 1.

@Orbit I see, can you change the layoutParams to this:
val layoutParams: GridLayout.LayoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams(  GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),  GridLayout.spec(0, 1, 1f) ).apply {  width = 0  height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT }

@Zain I believe the code you posted contains the same column layout specifications as my original code ((GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)). Regardless, I tried that code and it did not fix the column issue.

I haven't testes this but I think this will solve your problem (I believe there is a simpler solution using column span and column weight):
get number of all cells totalCells = gridLayout.getColumnCount()
then add 4 x (total row) - totalCells empty cells (using Space) to the total cells.
For example, in the case of 1 row and 1 view, we need to add 4 x 1 - 1 = 3 empty space to the gridlayout.

I've been able to artificially force the single cell to match the width of the other cells by adding additional invisible "mock" cells, sort of like you suggest. However, that's not something I'd like to do in production and I'm hoping for an alternative, "official" way of doing it.

Since GridLayout calculates column weights according to the highest possible weight of all rows (horizontally) in the layout,
    //gridlayout source code
    private float calculateTotalWeight() {
        float totalWeight = 0.0F;
        int i = 0;

        for(int N = GridLayout.this.getChildCount(); i < N; ++i) {
            View c = GridLayout.this.getChildAt(i);
            if (c.getVisibility() != 8) {
                LayoutParams lp = GridLayout.this.getLayoutParams(c);
                Spec spec = this.horizontal ? lp.columnSpec : lp.rowSpec;
                totalWeight += spec.weight;
            }
        }

        return totalWeight;
    }

a dummy view with
GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 0, 0f),                                        
GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 4, 4f)

can be added to tell GridLayout that the sum of the weights is not 1 (by default), but for example 4 or 5.
OR
one can check if the number of cells is less than number of columns then use a LinearLayout instead of GridLayout
See also this post. It might help. (i.e. using Recyclerview instead of GridLayout)
